# Add <errno.h> to "my_header.h" leads to error message

Tags: errno

I'm trying to print 'error number' from `errno.h` in my_func. If i include `<errno.h>` in my_func.c directly everything is Ok. But if i include `<errno.h>` in `"my_header.h"` and then include `"my_header.h"` in my_func.c compiler spits out the error:

> `src/my_func.c: warning: incompatible integer to pointer conversion passing 'int' to parameter of type 'int (*(*)())' [-Wint-conversion]
>                 return (print_errno(errno));`

---

> `/usr/include/sys/errno.h:81:15: note: expanded from macro 'errno'
>                 #define errno (*__error())`

my_func.c:

```
#include "my_header.h"

int my_func(void)
{
  if (write(5, "Hello, world!", 13) == -1)
     return(print_errno(errno));
}
```

my_header.h:

```
#include <errno.h>

int print_errno(int errno);
```

print_errno.c:

```
#include "my_header.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int print_errno(int errno)
{
  printf("error number = %d", errno);
  return (-1);

}
```

Why do i have this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have named your parameter `errno` which is expanded by the preprocessor, due this

```
 #define errno (*__error())
```

(errno.h)

So this prototype

```
int print_errno(int errno);
```

expands to

```
int print_errno(int (*__error()));
```

Short fix, don't call your parameter `errno`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work out. Still the same problem.

Comment: I just tried your code - I changed the parameter name to e in both print_errno.c and my_header.h and it compiled fine

Comment: Thank you for help!